# Isolating divs in Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Having a slight issue with BeautifulSoup and Python.

I'm trying to isolate the Title which is in a

```
 < a href="">TITLE<?/a>
```

The code I use is:

```
for box in soup ('div', {'class': 'box'}):
    for a in box.findnext('a'):
       print a
```

This works perfectly however, there is one div that is causing an issue. The usual one is:

```
<div class='box'>
```

The awkward one is:

```
<div class='box sponsored'>
```

How do I only select the first box and not the box sponsered?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BeautifulSoup` has a [special handling for the `class` attribute](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class):

> Remember that a single tag can have multiple values for its “class”
>   attribute. When you search for a tag that matches a certain CSS class,
>   you’re matching against any of its CSS classes.

One way to enforce `BeautifulSoup` to look at `div` elements with a single `box` class is to use the following [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select('div[class=box]')
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> data = """
... <div class='box'>
...     test1
... </div>
... <div class='box sponsored'>
...     test2
... </div>
... """
>>> 
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html')
>>> 
>>> for div in soup.select('div[class=box]'):
...     print div.text.strip()
... 
test1
```